Electron app's "cannot find module error"
Im making an audio enhancer application in electron but as i click on the enhance button in getting this error on console
(node:7587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/adi/spectrum/node_modules/tone/build/esm/core/Global' imported from /home/adi/spectrum/node_modules/tone/build/esm/index.js
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:264:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:924:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1137:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36)
(Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 8)

,main js:
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false, // Consider revisiting for security in future development
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js') // Optional preload script for additional security (refer to Electron documentation)
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

try {
  ipcMain.on('enhance-audio', async (event, filePath) => {
  
    const Tone = await import('tone')
  
    const player = new Tone.Player(filePath).toDestination()
    const eq = new Tone.EQ({
      low: 0, 
      mid: 1,
      high: 0
    }).toDestination()
    player.connect(eq)
    player.start()
  
    const outputPath = 'enhanced_audio.mp3' // Replace with your logic
    event.sender.send('enhancement-complete', outputPath)
  })
  
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error",error)
}

this is a main js file, which is responsible for much of the work.
below is renderer.js
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer

const audioUpload = document.getElementById('audio-upload')
const enhanceButton = document.getElementById('enhance-button')
const outputFilename = document.getElementById('output-filename')

enhanceButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const filePath = audioUpload.files[0].path
  console.log("Sending file path:", filePath);
  ipcRenderer.send('enhance-audio', filePath)
})

ipcRenderer.on('enhancement-complete', (event, outputPath) => {
  outputFilename.textContent = `Enhanced file: ${outputPath}`
})

this is index html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Spectrum</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Audio Enhancer</h1>
  <input type="file" id="audio-upload">
  <button id="enhance-button">Enhance</button>
  <p id="output-filename"></p>

  <script src="renderer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

and
this is my package json
{
  "name": "spectrum",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^30.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "tone": "^14.9.17"
  }
}

I tried Gemini and CHATGPT and tried to re import libs but its working

What version of Node is this?

hey check again ive updated question

change  "const Tone = await import('tone')" line as  "const Tone = require('tone')" or move the line to top of the page.

no its not working

A quick search in the issues of Tone.js shows that a lot of people got the same error as you (see issues #973 and #1077 for example). The reason you get this error is because Tone.js is an ESM package. It means that unless your Electron app is also ESM, you can't use it. You have two solutions:

Make your app ESM

For this, you can follow the official documentation. The correct import would then be:
import * as Tone from "tone";


Downgrade the version of the package

You can downgrade the version of Tone.js to before it became an ESM package. According to the issues (because it seems that both the package documentation an releases lack this information), it would be version 14.7.0.
Not using ESM (or a bundler), also means you can't use ES6 import syntax, you have to use CJS require:
const Tone = require("tone");


thanks for the answer, but downgrading is not working.

@ADITYA What "not working" means? What error do you get? Have you updated the import as well? You need to give more details.

Hey, I tried what you told but i was not getting the enhanced audio file

@ADITYA I gave you the solution for your error, for the rest you will have to read the docs of the library.
